# Deleting values from multiple arrays that have a particular value

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

Lets say I have two arrays: `a = array([1,2,3,0,4,5,0])` and `b = array([1,2,3,4,0,5,6])`. I am interested in removing the instances where `a` and `b`are `0`. But I also want to remove the corresponding instances from both lists. Therefore what I want to end up with is `a = array([1,2,3,5])` and `b = array([1,2,3,5])`. This is because `a[3] == 0` and `a[6] == 0`, so both `b[3]` and `b[6]` are also deleted. Likewise, since `b[4] == 0`, `a[4]` is also deleted.Its simple to do this for say two arrays:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2,3,0,4,5,0])
b = np.array([1,2,3,4,0,5,6])

ix = np.where(b == 0)
b = np.delete(b, ix)
a = np.delete(a, ix)

ix = np.where(a == 0)
b = np.delete(b, ix)
a = np.delete(a, ix)
```

However this solution doesnt scale up if I have many many arrays (which I do). What would be a more elegant way to do this?

If I try the following:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,2,3,0,4,5,0])
b = np.array([1,2,3,4,0,5,6])

arrays = [a,b]

for array in arrays:
    ix = np.where(array == 0)
    b = np.delete(b, ix)
    a = np.delete(a, ix)
```

I get `a = array([1, 2, 3, 4])` and `b = array([1, 2, 3, 0])`, not the answers I need. Any idea where this is wrong?

Comment: do all arrays have the same length?

Comment: @dnalow Yes they have the same length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because when you return from np.delete, you get an array that is stored in b and a inside the loop. However, the arrays stored in the arrays variable are copies, not references. Hence, when you're updating the arrays by deleting them, it deletes with regard to the original arrays. The first loop will return the corrects indices of 0 in the array but the second loop will return ix as 4 (look at the original array).
Like if you display the arrays variable in each iteration, it is going to remain the same.
You need to reassign arrays once you are done processing one array so that it's taken into consideration the next iteration. Here's how you'd do it -

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 0, 4, 5, 0])
b = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 5, 6])
arrays = [a,b]
for i in range(0, len(arrays)):
  ix = np.where(arrays[i] == 0)
  b = np.delete(b, ix)
  a = np.delete(a, ix)
  arrays = [a, b]
```

Of course you can automate what happens inside the loop. I just wanted to give an explanation of what was happening.

Comment: The reassignment is pretty clever, but wouldn't this fall into a copy-paste problem when scaling to larger array sets, or variable array sizes?

Comment: I'm trying to think of something that does not involve copy pasting. Perhaps make a numpy array of the numpy arrays... Will try and get back if I happen to find a way around!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming both/all arrays always have the same length, you can use [masks](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays):

```
ma = a != 0 # mask elements which are not equal to zero in a
mb = b != 0 # mask elements which are not equal to zero in b
m = ma * mb # assign the intersection of ma and mb to m
print a[m], b[m] # [1 2 3 5] [1 2 3 5]
```

You can of course also do it in one line

```
m = (a != 0) * (b != 0)
```

Or use the inverse

```
ma = a == 0
mb = b == 0
m = ~(ma + mb) # not the union of ma and mb
```

Comment: Was not familiar with masks, @Christoph Terasa. Elegant!

Answer (score 0):

A slow method involves operating over the whole list twice, first to build an intermediate list of indices to delete, and then second to delete all of the values at those indices:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,2,3,0,4,5,0])
b = np.array([1,2,3,4,0,5,6])

arrays = [a, b]
vals = []

for array in arrays:
    ix = np.where(array == 0)
    vals.extend([y for x in ix for y in x.tolist()])

vals = list(set(vals))

new_array = []
for array in arrays:
    new_array.append(np.delete(array, vals))
```

Comment: Doesn't the OP want the indices to change after every iteration?

Comment: They say they want to remove from both lists the elements at the indices where at least one of the lists contains a 0. And their use of `b[4] == 0` indicates they mean they don't necessarily want to delete the `a` values from `b` first before deleting the `b` values from `a`. To me, that says, 'build a list of all indices, and then delete all values.'

Answer (score 0):

Building up on top of Christoph Terasa's answer, you can use array operations instead of for loops:

```
arrays = np.vstack([a,b]) # ...long list of arrays of equal length

zeroind = (arrays==0).max(0)

pos_arrays = arrays[:,~zeroind] # a 2d array only containing those columns where none of the lines contained zeros
```